# RaLink 3090 unstable wireless connection

Tags: wireless, networking, connection

Recently I moved from Windows, and since I installed a Linux distro my wireless connection is uncommonly slow (~50kb/s from ~2mb/s). I got no problems using wired Internet from the same router. I've read about alot of possible issues around the web the past couple of days, i tried disabling ipv6 and n connection, wicd, edited nsswitch.conf, did wlan0 power off, got rt2800 firmware pack(i think that here is the problem, no fix found tho), checked blacklist, modified channel and dns and etc.

What i got is, that every time i connect to my wireless network my internet is good for the first 1-2 minutes, then it drops. I think that this would explain the problem to a person, that is into network and wireless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also have RT3090 on Ubuntu. 
My wifi only works on TKIP type encription, if the network has AES, it does not work at all.
I changed my configs on my router and my internet connection at home is fine.
Otherwise, I have to log on Windows. I have tried multiple solutions including the ones you said above and none of them worked. I also tried on Debian, Mint as well.

Sorry if it does not solve your problem but at least is something you may try. An also about my english, not my native language.